# How extract private static constant in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring, keyboard-shortcuts, constants

To extract constant I can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, that "extraction" create **public** constant:

```
public static final String CONST = "123";
```

So I need **manually** type private. Is there a way to extract constant with private scope by default?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> twice (shows `Extract Constant` dialog)

hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (set default `Visibility` to `Private`)

hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

Done :)  The private scope is set default - so you can use constant extraction as before, to change default scope simply repeat steps above with choosing different scope.

Comment: I use Intellij Idea Community Edition 12.1.4,  so "ctlr + shift + e" do not show Extract Constatnc dialog for me. Is it version problem?

Comment: My mistake - putted shift+e instead alt+c (that copy pasting in early morning):))

Comment: Remember to hit it twice:)

Comment: Yeee! this is what I really want 8)

Comment: At current time I have no shortcut allocated to extracting constants (only "refactor this" where I then can choose what I want to do). Is there a possibility to show this dialog on another way? Just curious. Your answer still helped me, thanks :)

Comment: @BAERUS in `Settings` -> `Keymap` look for `Main menu`/`Refactor`/`Extract`/`Constant`, right click or enter to reveal the contextual menu that allows to `Add Keyboard Shortcut` and set it to `CTRL+ALT+C`. The default extraction shortcuts (for IntelliJ IDEA on Windows) are: `Variable: CTRL+ALT+V`, `Constant: CTRL+ALT+C`, `Field: CTRL+ALT+F`, `Parameter: CTRL+ALT+P`,

Comment: @BAERUS or if you don't want to set the keyboard shortcuts, you can always do (while the cursor is on the value you want to extract) `CTRL+SHIFT+A` and start typing `Constant` (or `Variable` or `Field` or `Parameter`) and the menu should show the corresponding action (which is under `Refactor | Extract`). This method requires more typing but can still save you some time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> If the Enable in place refactorings check box is cleared on the Editor
>   settings, the Extract Constant refactoring is performed by means of
>   the Extract Constant Dialog dialog box.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/extract-constant.html

Extract Constant Dialog allows choose the appropriate scope of constant

Settings -> Editors -> Enable Place refactoring